# What can be a module for Magento Search solution?

Tags: magento

I am looking Magento module that has instant search feature, which is fast. I have more than 150k products on my store.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Check **Solr** - But this is more a server based module than a Magento extension.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many solutions and Sphinx or Solr are the best solutions according to my experience.

Answer (score 0):

SOlR search is recommended as a search solution for Magento sites with lots of Products.

As SOlR is having its own data handling structure so it reduces Mysql load.
Also it handles search attribute weight value when searching which results in a better search result.

With enterprise version SOLR module is integrated by default.

With community version you will have to purchase a commercial SOLR bridge module and integrate.

There are other search modules like Sphinx etc but from wherever I have searched and read on Forum SOLR is recommended.